# Update salary field value with 10 percent of each employee in employee collection in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

Please help me me out, i want to write a query in mongoDB which should be equivalent to the following MYSQL query.

Query -

```
UPDATE emp SET salary = salary + (salary * 10)/100;
```

MongoDB `emp` Collection Format is like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ddce430d308e8d473ded8d"),
    "name" : "Ravi",
    "salary" : 6000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ddce570d308e8d473ded8e"),
    "name" : "John",
    "salary" : 10000
}
```

I want to update both document with 10% increment in salary of each Employee.
Note- MongoDB Version is 3.2

Comment: You mean `1.1 x`?

Comment: Your question has nothing about mysql. You should remove mysql tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$mul](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/mul/) operator like this

```
db.emp.update({ "name": { $in: ["Ravi", "John"] } }, { $mul: { salary: 1.1 } });
```